# Cropping videos to perfectly fit YouTube 16:9 dimensions with PiTiVi or Kdenlive?

Tags: video, youtube, pitivi, kdenlive

I'm using RecordMyDesktop to generate videos for some tutorials and I've tried using quite a lot of video editing programs but haven't been able to get these videos to fit perfectly into the YouTube dimensions (without the black margins).

How can I do this without losing video quality?

**Some more info that might help**

Running ffmpeg -i on the files returns the following:

Stream #0.1: Video: theora, yuv420p, 944x512 [PAR 1:1 DAR 59:32], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc - although I have various files, each with different dimensions.

I've tried the following editors: Kdenlive, PiTiVi, Avidemux & Cinelerra (I prefer the first 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier and better to resize the window you're recording to 1280x720 (or any 16:9 proportion).

`xdotool getactivewindow windowsize 1280 720` will do it for you.

---

If you really want to do the cropping, it's quite easy in Kdenlive:

- Right-click on a clip in the timeline, go to **Add Effect** → **Crop and transform** → **Crop**.
- Check **Automatic center-crop**, or try different settings until you get the desired result.

Comment: crop didn't work for me for some reason, but I've finally found out how to record exact dimensions with RecordMyDesktop, you need to use the CLI with something like: recordmydesktop --width 1280 --height 720 --full-shots --fps 15 --channels 1 --device hw:1,0 --delay 4 --no-sound -y 100

Answer (score 0):

For Pitivi, in 2023, I use this process:

- first, change the rendering project settings to change the size of your output video file:

  - click Render > Advanced > Project Settings
  - go to the Size section and set your desired Width and Height for the final video.
- second, shift the video into position:

  - go back to the main window > Clip tab > Transformation section
  - set X and Y to negative offset values to shift the portion of the input video you want to keep into the cropped output region.
- finally, you can render the video, and it should cropped to the size and region you specified.

I wrote a blog post about it which has some pretty pictures and video clips:

- https://tech.kosmokaryote.org/2023/11/technology-how-to-crop-video-in-pitivi.html

I was misled by an effect called Crop which does not actually seem to affect the size of the output video. :|